# daisy chain SAS tape drives?

Tags: sas, tape

I need to add a second SAS Tape drive to my server. I have a second PCI-E SAS card, however I don't have any free PCI slots in the server. Is there any way to daisy chain external SAS devices together from a single external SAS port? similar to the way external SCSI works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your SAS tape drive(s).

Do you see one SAS port or two SAS ports?

If you see one, you don't have any options to daisy-chain.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that's the beast. Only one port. I was hoping there was multi-lane external SFF-8088 cable option or something that I just wasn't finding on google.

Comment: You could buy a second tape drive specifically with both ports and leave this one at the end of the chain.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly SAS does support daisy-chaining but obviously individual products don't have to support that if they don't want. So it all comes down to the exact products you have, if you have a device that has both in and out ports then I say go for it - it won't be too hard to try and if it doesn't work you'll know about it pretty quickly.

On a separate note I can't believe you've been allowed to have that user namer on here for so long - would you consider changing it please as it infers some form of officiality that's not the case - sorry to be a pain about it but I'd sooner you change it than the admins.